# How to keep data after uninstall and reinstall android application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, google-plus-signin

In my application i am implementing google plus login.After successful login every user enter a reference code.If a user uninstall the application after entering correct reference code,reference code for that user cannot be lost.That means that if user reinstall app again,then app shouldn't ask for the reference code.Please give me a way solve this problem.

Comment: store data in database and put data base in sdcard...

Comment: you can keep device information in the server like its id

Comment: use database and save that file into sdcard/external storage whenever user install the app again check that file

Comment: @Mohit what about if the user format the device and SD card ?

Comment: then as @Sree said you can put it on server and fetch with specific user id..

Comment: yes i am keeping data in server but how to check that data

Comment: @krishna can you rephrase your question to make more sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store data that remains after uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022975/how-to-store-data-that-remains-after-uninstall)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Persist Data After Uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683614/android-persist-data-after-uninstall)