# How to save PrivateKey permanently on Android

Tags: java, android, android-security

I am developing an android application, how can I save a private key like string base64 in the device that persists even after uninstalling the app? It's possible?

Internal Storage or SDcard are not secure for a privatekey because can be read from others application, right?

Comment: yes, use internal/external storage to save data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store data that remains after uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022975/how-to-store-data-that-remains-after-uninstall)